# Set Parent through UI Automation

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, ui-automation, unified-service-desk

How can I set the parent window forcefully through UI Automation?

Let's say I have a Winform and I want to open command prompt inside it through UI Automation. Now, for that I will have to set Winform as parent and then open command prompt inside it.

Also, please note that I want to open it through UI Automation only.

Looking forward to your help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UI Automation is not for hacking apps, it's for automating them. You can't do such things with UIA.

Comment: I want some thing similar to the way we set parent through Win32 API. It is not for hacking................ Win32API.SetParent(parentHandle, ChildHandle);

Comment: If the UI doesnt give you a way to open a console, then you cant achieve it

Comment: I dont want to do it with console only.. there can be other application as well

Comment: Calling SetParent on a window you don't own as a developer *is* hacking. Sometimes it works.